# How does excel convert Julian dates to calender dates?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, excel, excel-2003

I have a Julian date of `41348` and Excel converts this Julian date to `3/15/2013`. Do you know the logic Excel uses to calculate the calender date? I need this same logic to convert Julian dates to calender dates in SQL Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`41348` is not julian date. Excel needs to use a formula to convert a julian date to a proper date. `183349` is an example of a julian date. `41348` is simply the number of days passed after `01/01/1900`.

You can add those number of days to `01/01/1900`, if I recall correctly, in SQL server to get the desired results.

EDIT: Yup, use `DATEADD`. Add a column with `01/01/1900`

```
UPDATE Table
SET NewDate = DATEADD(Days, RawDate-2, '01/01/1900')
```

You need to remove 1 from the RawDate since `1` corresponds to `01/01/1900` and another `1` apparently I'm not sure where, but investigating.

On my SQL Server2008R2, apparently it considers `1900` to be a non-leap year. There goes the additional `1` to remove!

Answer (score 1):

I hope 41348 julian date is not equl to "3/15/2013"

The first two digits are year
and the next 3 digits represents for date 348 means Dec 14th.

I have done the same with below expression in Sql.

Select DATEADD(day, CAST(RIGHT('41348',3) AS int) - 1, CONVERT(datetime, LEFT('41348',2) + '0101', 112))